# Technical Display logic in View or Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently am using a fontset to swap specific characters to symbols.

```
<% provide(:title, @card.name) %>
<div id="section" class="container-fluid cardLoader">
  <div class="cardContainer">
    <strong class='cardTitle'><%= @card.name %></strong><br>
    <div class="cardImage">
      <%= image_tag(@card.image_url) %>
    </div>
    <div class="cardStats">
      <ul class='cardStatLabel'>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Card Name</span>: <%= @card.name %></li>
        <span class='cardLabel'>Mana Cost</span>: 
        <!-- Hash Logic -->
        <% hash = { '{hw}' => '<span class="ms-half">
                            <i class="ms ms-w ms-cost"></i>
                           </span>', 
                '{W}' => '<i class="ms ms-w ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>', 
                '{R}' => '<i class="ms ms-r ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{U}' => '<i class="ms ms-u ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{G}' => '<i class="ms ms-g ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{B}' => '<i class="ms ms-b ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{W/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-wu ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-wb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-2w ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-ub ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-ur ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-2u ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-br ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-bg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-2b ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-rg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-rw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-2r ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-gw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-gb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-2g ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{0}' => '<i class="ms ms-0 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{1}' => '<i class="ms ms-1 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{2}' => '<i class="ms ms-2 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{3}' => '<i class="ms ms-3 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{4}' => '<i class="ms ms-4 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{5}' => '<i class="ms ms-5 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{6}' => '<i class="ms ms-6 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{7}' => '<i class="ms ms-7 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{8}' => '<i class="ms ms-8 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{9}' => '<i class="ms ms-9 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{10}' => '<i class="ms ms-10 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '+2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
                '−1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
                '−10' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-10"></i>',
                }%>
        <%= @card.manaCost.gsub(/\{.+?\}/){|k| hash[k] || k }.html_safe %></li>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Colors</span>: <%= @card.colors %></li>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Rarity</span>: <%= @card.rarity %></li>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Set</span>: <i class="ss ss-<%= @card.set.downcase %> ss-3x ss-common"></i>  <%= @card.setName %> - <%= @card.set %></li>
        <% if @card.text.nil? %>

        <% else %>
          <li><span class='cardLabel'>Card Text</span>: 
          <%= @card.text.gsub(/\{.+?\}|[\+\d:]/){|k| hash[k] || k }.html_safe %></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if @card.flavor.nil? %>
        <% else %>
          <li><span class='cardLabel'>Flavor Text</span>: <i><%= @card.flavor %></i></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if @card.power.nil? %>
        <% else %>
            <li><span class='cardLabel'>P/T</span>: <%= @card.power %>/<%= @card.toughness %></span></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I feel like this massive hash should live on Controller side but I'm having issues moving it over.

```
def card_format(att)
 hash = { '{hw}' => '<span class="ms-half">
                            <i class="ms ms-w ms-cost"></i>
                           </span>', 
                '{W}' => '<i class="ms ms-w ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>', 
                '{R}' => '<i class="ms ms-r ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{U}' => '<i class="ms ms-u ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{G}' => '<i class="ms ms-g ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{B}' => '<i class="ms ms-b ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{W/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-wu ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-wb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-2w ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-ub ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-ur ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-2u ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-br ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-bg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-2b ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-rg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-rw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-2r ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-gw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-gb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-2g ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{0}' => '<i class="ms ms-0 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{1}' => '<i class="ms ms-1 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{2}' => '<i class="ms ms-2 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{3}' => '<i class="ms ms-3 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{4}' => '<i class="ms ms-4 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{5}' => '<i class="ms ms-5 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{6}' => '<i class="ms ms-6 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{7}' => '<i class="ms ms-7 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{8}' => '<i class="ms ms-8 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{9}' => '<i class="ms ms-9 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{10}' => '<i class="ms ms-10 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '+2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
                '−1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
                '−10' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-10"></i>'

  att.gsub(/\{.+?\}/){|k| hash[k] || k }.html_safe            
end
```

Causes a crash on att.gsub. My 'hash' logic could also be simplified, maybe? I figured out

How would I move this to the controller/ It should exist in the controller, right?

Comment: can you add some samples of `att` I don't realy understood what do you meen "but my current RegEx requires the Brackets (Which they don't have)"

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Thanks for the reply - I actually figured that part out. 
/\{.+?\}|[\+\d:]/  -- I needed to find out how to include +2, -1, -10, +1 etc etc to my HASH regex. Now I'm just unsure where to put the Hash in the controller.

Comment: you have to add this method in helper or decorator, NOT in controller, NOT in view

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Ahhh Helpers, I always forget about those. Let me try and add to my post.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Wow that worked perfectly - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg recommended in the comment, a 'Helper' is what I wanted.

**Working Helper:**

```
module CardsHelper
  def card_text_mana card
    hash = {    '{hw}' => '<span class="ms-half">
                            <i class="ms ms-w ms-cost"></i>
                           </span>', 
                '{W}' => '<i class="ms ms-w ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>', 
                '{R}' => '<i class="ms ms-r ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{U}' => '<i class="ms ms-u ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{G}' => '<i class="ms ms-g ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{B}' => '<i class="ms ms-b ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{W/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-wu ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-wb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-2w ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-ub ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-ur ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-2u ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-br ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-bg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-2b ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-rg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-rw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-2r ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-gw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-gb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-2g ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{0}' => '<i class="ms ms-0 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{1}' => '<i class="ms ms-1 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{2}' => '<i class="ms ms-2 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{3}' => '<i class="ms ms-3 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{4}' => '<i class="ms ms-4 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{5}' => '<i class="ms ms-5 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{6}' => '<i class="ms ms-6 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{7}' => '<i class="ms ms-7 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{8}' => '<i class="ms ms-8 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{9}' => '<i class="ms ms-9 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{10}' => '<i class="ms ms-10 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '+2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
                '−1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
                '−10' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-10"></i>',
                }
    card.gsub(/\{.+?\}|[\+\d:]/){|k| hash[k] || k }.html_safe 
  end
end
```

**View Logic**

```
<% provide(:title, @card.name) %>
<div id="section" class="container-fluid cardLoader">
  <div class="cardContainer">
    <strong class='cardTitle'><%= @card.name %></strong><br>
    <div class="cardImage">
      <%= image_tag(@card.image_url) %>
    </div>
    <div class="cardStats">
      <ul class='cardStatLabel'>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Card Name</span>: <%= @card.name %></li>
        <span class='cardLabel'>Mana Cost</span>: 
        <%= card_text_mana(@card.manaCost) %></li>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Converted Mana Cost</span>: <%= @card.cmc %></li>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Rarity</span>: <%= @card.rarity %></li>
        <li><span class='cardLabel'>Set</span>: <i class="ss ss-<%= @card.set.downcase %> ss-3x ss-common"></i>  <%= @card.setName %> - <%= @card.set %></li>
        <% if @card.text.nil? %>

        <% else %>
          <li><span class='cardLabel'>Card Text</span>: 
          <%= card_text_mana(@card.text) %></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if @card.flavor.nil? %>
        <% else %>
          <li><span class='cardLabel'>Flavor Text</span>: <i><%= @card.flavor %></i></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if @card.power.nil? %>
        <% else %>
            <li><span class='cardLabel'>P/T</span>: <%= @card.power %>/<%= @card.toughness %></span></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Works perfectly now. (Likely will re-name)